# How to run a script after testing my .exe in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am aware that you can run a command after building, but how do I run a command after running the .exe I just built? I saw a tutorial that had a "Post test" option, but I can't find in my project configuration.

[image]

Comment: Which visual studio version you use and which you saw ? vc6++ , 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Visual Studio, you can use the MSbuild to create a build script.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx

Above the is the documentation. Here you can create a build script so it will compile the project you are working on and then action some separate tests.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393573.aspx

here is a tutorial for the build system. Then you could integreate this with jenkins for more testing and configuration purposes.

http://www.infoq.com/articles/MSBuild-1

This might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

I usually write a wrapper .bat script that first calls the executable, and afterwards any other command of choice.  Then change the "Debugging" preferences to run the batch file instead of the created executable.